# exec from nested function / vnd implemention

Tags: python

I would like implement VND algorithm in Python.

Under solve function, I created some moves functions: move1...move2..etc
I created VND function which switchs between those functions based on the improvment criterion.

I tried used exec but it isnt work:  exec ("move" + str(i) + "(route)")

```
def VND(route,k_max):
    s_better=route.copy()
    k=1
    while k<=k_max:
        s_k=exec ("move" + str(k) + "(route)")
        if s_k<s_better:
            k=1
        else: k=k+1
```

1. Why doesn't it work?
2. I would like to know if I can implement it in another way

thanks!!

Comment: Are these `"move" + str(k)` functions defined?

Comment: use list `moves` and later `moves[0]`, `moves[1]`, etc.  `s_k = moves[k]` or dictinary `func["move1(route)"]`, `func["move2(route)"]`, s_k = `func["move" + str(k) + "(route)"]`

Answer (score 0):

Keep functions on list

```
moves = [
   move1,
   move2,
]

moves.append(move3)
```

and later you can use

```
s_k = moves[k-1](route)
```

---

Eventually keep in dictionary

```
moves = {
   "move1": move1,
   "move2": move2,
]

moves["move3"] = move3
```

and later you can use

```
s_k = moves["move" + str(k)](route)
```